# web based scanning solution

Tags: web, scanner, scanning

Are you guys aware of any web based scanning software? I prefer open source, if not commercial. You should be able to scan documents and upload directly onto a web server? perhaps based on ActiveX...

Comment: don't know if it can help (as it implies coding), but SilverLight, with out-of-browser trusted execution, can run COM objects. Especially, it can run the WAI com objects...

Answer (score 0):

Anything running within the browser should **never** have permission to talk directly to the hardware like this (I guess ActiveX might make it possible since it throws the security model out of the window).

If the scanner is directly attached to the network or to a computer which supports [SANE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_Access_Now_Easy) (e.g. the webserver) then it would be straightforward to code. Note this implies that you control the config of the device where the scanner is attached - but you really don't want to allow anyone to save their scans on your server.

Comment: [Disclosure: the idea presented here is subject to at least one patent owned by my employer] A browser has permission to talk directly to at least one kind of hardware, a web server. Any scanner that exposes a web interface (e.g. `GET http://scanner.local/scan.JPG`) can be accessed safely from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [phpSane](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/)